# c# application not working without vc 10 runtime

Tags: c#, crash, runtime

my application crashed on startup on a machine without visual studio so i installed it and figured the only this i need to make my app run is :
Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x86 Runtime - 10.0.30319

However when i uninstantiated this component and installed Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86), which is said to include the runtime components, my application still crashes.

How do i make it work? am i installing a wrong package? thanks

Comment: Visual Studio installs the .Net framework as well - you don't mention whether this is installed correctly on the target machine. Is it?

Comment: @Darksider im using .net 4 and that is installed correctly. basically application only fails if i uninstall Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x86 Runtime - 10.0.30319 component, which i thought to get from this package which i mention above, because i cant install visual studio on every pc

Answer (score 0):

Which .Net Framework version are you targetting?

Is this a WPF, Winforms, Console Application?

If I understand you correctly:

You built a C# application and it runs on your development computer but when you try to run it on another system it fails?

Perhaps you need to include a prerequisite when you publish the application?  In the project properties -> Publish tab.  Check the Application Files and Prerequisite buttons to see if you need to include some items with your installer.

Comment: It is under .Net 4, and it is WinForms application. it doesnt work when runtime is not installed on machine, that comes with visual studio, but i cant install it on everypc, so i need a way to install it separately, or somehow include it during build. i will check abt prerequisite and update. thx

Comment: i checked both Application Files and Prerequisite but nothing unusual or extra that i dont include

Comment: In the Application Files button make sure you click Show all files

Comment: i did. there is nothing extra. Anyway the problem is that i need runtime component installed on user machine to run the application. however re-distributable package doesn't seem to install this component, is there a way to statically link it during build on my developer machine where i have VS installed

Answer (score 0):

Found a fix in case someone have the same problem:

created setup project for my application, it automatically detected dependencies,
then manually added Microsoft_VC100_DebugCRT_x86.msm to setup project : Project -> Add-> Merged Module. Build and install .msi on a user machine.